# Using Select-String (PowerShell) to find a word from error file

Tags: select-string

I have the following code

```
Select-String -path errors.log -Pattern 'VirtualMachine\s*-vm-' | %{$_.Matches 
| Select Value}
```

It outputs:

```
Value

--

VirtualMachine-vm-
```

The error file has VirtualMachine-vm-12345 but will change so I need to find not an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select-String -path errors.log -Pattern 'VirtualMachine\s*-vm-\d\d\d\d\d\d' | %{$_.Matches | Select Value}
```

I figured it out
How do I run Get-VM -ID on this value?

Update
here is the answer:

```
$match = Select-String -path C:\errors.log -Pattern 'VirtualMachine\s*-vm-\d\d\d\d\d\d' | %{$_.Matches | Select -expand Value}

Get-VM -id $match | ft -Property Name,ID -AutoSize
```